# C# Find 2 strongest values from 4 max/min selections

Tags: c#, max, min

All values range from -100.0f to 100.0f

```
public float happysad = 0.0f;
public float passiveagressive = 0.0f;
public float friendenemy = 0.0f;
public float weakstrong = 0.0f;

void GetStrongestTwo() {
    /* Work out the 2 most extreme values
    if (happysad > 0){
            sad is the strongest
    }
    if (happysad < 0){
            sad is the strongest
    }
    Need to do this for all then work out the two that have the largest (either positive or negative value)
    */ 
}
```

I have tried constant if statements, but with my understanding of max and min there should be an easier way. My attempts have resulted in 24 if statements. An alternative way would be to separate the values to the following.

```
public float happy = 0.0f;
public float sad = 0.0f;
public float passive = 0.0f;
public float agressive = 0.0f;
public float friend = 0.0f;
public float enemy = 0.0f;
public float weak = 0.0f;
public float strong = 0.0f;
```

My question is what would be the best approach to this challenge? If a coding method exists and I just need more research I would appreciate a push in the right direction, or if the 2nd solution is more viable then I will compensate for it in my code later on. As the values are opposing I would rather just have to add or remove a value of 1.0f each time an event happens that impacts the emotion element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using those many variables and a lot of if's, create a simple class with name and value, like:

```
public class GameInfo
{
  public string name;
  public float value;
  public GameInfo(string name, float value)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Now, you can easily have a *sorted* list with those values. Like this:

```
    List<GameInfo> info = new List<GameInfo>();

    // please add the other info you wish
    info.Add(new GameInfo("happy", 5.0f));
    info.Add(new GameInfo("sad", 15.0f));
    info.Add(new GameInfo("passive", 4.0f));
    info.Add(new GameInfo("agressive", 35.0f));
    // ...

    // sort the list (I used linq but you could use other methods)
    List<GameInfo> sortedInfo = info.OrderByDescending(o => o.value).ToList();

    foreach (GameInfo i in sortedInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i.name + ", " + i.value);
    }
```

And that's it.

Comment: Bravo, this is so elegant. This method is a lot more efficient than how I was looking at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By "strongest", do you mean you're trying to find values with the highest magnitude?  And do you just need the values, or the names of the variables?

If you just need the values, you can do:

```
float happysad = -10.0f;
float passiveaggressive = 5.0f;
float friendenemy = 2.0f;
float weakstrong = 7.0f;

var twoStrongest = 
    new [] {happysad, passiveaggressive, friendenemy, weakstrong}
        .Select(stat => new {Value = stat, Magnitude = Math.Abs(stat)})
        .OrderByDescending(statWithMagnitude => statWithMagnitude.Magnitude)
        .Select(statWithMagnitude => statWithMagnitude.Value)
        .Take(2).ToList();
```

What the above does: maps each float to a temporary object that has the magnitude of each stat, sorts it by magnitude, then converts it back to the original float, and takes the first two values.

On the other hand, if you want to find the names, you can store the name/stat mapping in a dictionary:

```
var stats = new Dictionary<string, float> {
    {"happysad",  -10.0f},
    {"passiveaggressive",  -6.0f},
    {"friendenemy",  8.0f},
    {"weakstrong",  3.0f}
};

var twoStrongest = stats
    .Select(entry => new {Entry = entry, Magnitude = Math.Abs(entry.Value)})
    .OrderByDescending(statWithMagnitude => statWithMagnitude.Magnitude)
    .Select(statWithMagnitude => statWithMagnitude.Entry)
    .Take(2).ToList();
```

Above returns a list of key/value pairs containing the name and the original value.